# need help deciphering tensorflow feed InvalidArgumentError

Tags: tensorflow

I don't think I understand this feed error from tensorflow

```
Debug:  [[ 0.  0.]]
Debug: (1, 2)
Debug: float64

2018-05-09 09:56:34.615561: W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:295] _0_input_producer: Skipping cancelled enqueue attempt with queue not closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kiran/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1323, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/kiran/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1302, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/home/kiran/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'seqModel/a_prev' with dtype double and shape [1,2]
         [[Node: seqModel/a_prev = Placeholder[dtype=DT_DOUBLE, shape=[1,2], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

the way I feed the placeholder is:

```
self.a_prev = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[1,2], name='a_prev')

batch = tf.train.batch([self.x_acc, self.y_acc,
                        self.prev_pos], 
                        batch_size=1, capacity=20000, num_threads=1)

x_acc, y_acc, prev_pos = sess.run(batch)
test = np.array([[ x_acc[0,0], y_acc[0,0] ]])

print("Debug: ",test)
print("Debug:",test.shape)
print("Debug:",test.dtype)

_,X_hat_val,loss_val, X_val = sess.run([train,X_hat,loss, self.X],  
                                    feed_dict={self.a_prev : np.array([[x_acc[0,0],y_acc[0,0] ]]),
self.pos1 :  np.array([[ prev_pos[0,0] ]])
})
```

The error does not make sense because I am feeding values to the placeholder but it says that there are no values. What does that mean?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your error couldn't be reproduced with the code you provided.

Comment: I have a repository on github https://github.com/knkumar/sequence-prediction/blob/experimental/KalmanModel.py detailing the complete code but provided the essential details to make it easy to process

Comment: I am sorry it took me some time to push the code to the repo. it should be showing the self.a_prev on line 25.

Answer (score 1):

NB: I didn't run your code, as it depends on unavailable data.

However, it's probable your error is caused by reassigning the `self.a_prev` attribute, line [173](https://github.com/knkumar/sequence-prediction/blob/experimental/KalmanModel.py#L173). With this line, `self.a_prev` doesn't point to the `tf.placeholder(..., name='a_prev')` anymore, but to a different `Tensor` (from `self.new_evidence`) - so the actual placeholder doesn't get fed when running.

---

**Toy example for this supposition**

```python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_acc = np.random.rand(2, 2)
y_acc = np.random.rand(2, 2)

a_prev = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[1,2], name='a_prev')
some_results = tf.add(a_prev, 1.)

a_prev = tf.constant([[-1, -1]])
# ... now "a_prev" the python variable isn't pointing to the placeholder anymore,
# so "a_prev" the placeholder exists in the graph with no python pointer to it.

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(some_results, feed_dict={a_prev : np.array([[x_acc[0,0],y_acc[0,0] ]])})
    # "a_prev" the constant is assigned the values, not "a_prev" the placeholder, 
    # hence an error.
```

> **InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'a_prev' with dtype double and shape [1,2]**
>   [[Node: a_prev = Placeholderdtype=DT_DOUBLE, shape=[1,2],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]    [[Node: Add/_1 = _Recvclient_terminated=false,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_8_Add",
>   tensor_type=DT_DOUBLE,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Comment: Thanks for your analysis. I see your point but the error is identifying "value for placeholder tensor 'seqModel/a_prev'" a_prev as a placeholder tensor. I am sure that will give me errors at a later point.

Comment: Just to clarify my hypothesis: your error is that the placeholder with `name='seqModel/a_prev'` isn't fed values, even though you are giving to your `feed_dict` the key `self.a_prev` with some values. Hence my supposition that `self.a_prev` isn't pointing to the placeholder anymore (TF would notice that the actual placeholder named `seqModel/a_prev` isn't actually fed, and throw such an error with its name). I edited my answer with an example. (once again, I may be wrong and something else is causing this)